# How to include nice Facebook, Twitter, G+ share buttons?

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter, google-plus

I want to create a nice  Facebook, Twiter, G+ share buttons like they are in Youtube:

[image]

What I got is a default buttons which are not so nice:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="icon" share_url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a>

<g:plusone annotation="none"></g:plusone>
```

[image]

Comment: Create these icons yourself and link them with your target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/nJQbh/) using 'addthis'

Comment: Do I have to include something extra in header etc, because I just paste your code in my website ant it's not working.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f868b690b0a89f1"></script>

Answer (score 3):

http://www.addthis.com/ lets you add these to your site without needing to create icons yourself. You can optionally include Analytics tracking on them and configure lots of aspects of how the buttons look.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for google+ nor twitter, but for facebook you should not be doing it.

In order to pull that off you'll have to use the "facebook sharer" which has been deprecated and is no longer supported as it states [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

And [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

You should use the [Like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) or [Send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) buttons instead, though you can not control how they look (you can to some extent, but not what you meant)